# Remove duplicated rows

Tags: r, duplicates, r-faq

I have read a `CSV` file into an R data.frame. Some of the rows have the same element in one of the columns. I would like to remove rows that are duplicates in that column. For example:

```
platform_external_dbus          202           16                     google        1
platform_external_dbus          202           16         space-ghost.verbum        1
platform_external_dbus          202           16                  localhost        1
platform_external_dbus          202           16          users.sourceforge        8
platform_external_dbus          202           16                    hughsie        1
```

I would like only one of these rows since the others have the same data in the first column.

Comment: which one do you want?  just the first?  in other words: do you want to keep `google` or `localhost` or `hughsie` ?

Comment: It does not matter for this part of my statistical analysis. I am only trying to relate the project title (first column), the number of bugs (second column), and the number of organizations on the project (third column).

Comment: cool.  throw unnecessary columns out and use ?unique

Answer (score 231, accepted):

just isolate your data frame to the columns you need, then use the unique function  :D

```
# in the above example, you only need the first three columns
deduped.data <- unique( yourdata[ , 1:3 ] )
# the fourth column no longer 'distinguishes' them, 
# so they're duplicates and thrown out.
```

Comment: This looks like it will work perfectly. Can you please explain to me what is happening with the `[,1:3]` part of that code? I'm new to R which is why I'm asking what I can only assume is an obvious question.

Comment: @user1897691 mark it as correct then ;)  [watch this](http://www.screenr.com/fCs8) and if you like that, check [twotorials.com](http://twotorials.com)

Comment: Do note that this will remove all the columns except for the three first ones.

Answer (score 298):

For people who have come here to look for a general answer for duplicate row removal, use `!duplicated()`:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)

duplicated(df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

> df[duplicated(df), ]
  a b
2 A 1
6 B 1
8 C 2

> df[!duplicated(df), ]
  a b
1 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 1
7 C 2
```

Answer from: [Removing duplicated rows from R data frame](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/removing-duplicated-rows-from-r-data-frame)

By default this method will keep the **first occurrence** of each duplicate. You can use the argument `fromLast = TRUE` to instead keep the **last occurrence** of each duplicate. You can sort your data before this step so that it keeps the rows you want.

Comment: I want to create a new varibale that flags if there's a duplicate *on   a certain variable* almost like 

df$duplicates <- ifelse(this rows value in column a == previous row value in column a , 1 , 0)

Comment: @jacob see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows

Comment: This keeps the first appeared value and removes the rest of the duplicates, right? Or it removes values randomly?

Comment: @alphabetagamma yes, it keeps the first appeared value

Comment: If you are only interested in duplicates in certain columns, say cols 1 and 2, we can use `df[!duplicated(df[, 1:2])]`

Comment: this seems more verbose than using unique(). Any reason it has more upvotes?

Comment: `df` is the name of a base R function... It would be better to use `my_df` as the name of the data frame

Comment: @nateroe `duplicated()` is more general than `unique()`. As qwr's comment shows, with `duplicated` you can specify which columns to check for duplicates. With `unique` that is not so easily done. (With `unique()` you can keep the unique rows for only that set of columns, but it would take more work if you want to bring the other columns along as well.)

Answer (score 123):

The function [`distinct()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html) in the [`dplyr`](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package performs arbitrary duplicate removal, either from specific columns/variables (as in this question) or considering all columns/variables. `dplyr` is part of the [`tidyverse`](https://tidyverse.org).

**Data and package**

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1,2),4), b = rep(LETTERS[1:4],2))
```

**Remove rows duplicated in a specific column (e.g., column`a`)**

Note that `.keep_all = TRUE` retains all columns, otherwise only column `a` would be retained.

```
distinct(dat, a, .keep_all = TRUE)

  a b
1 1 A
2 2 B
```

**Remove rows that are complete duplicates of other rows:**

```
distinct(dat)

  a b
1 1 A
2 2 B
3 1 C
4 2 D
```

Comment: Great answer, by the way, `.keep_all` is for whether to keep all the columns, not to be mixed with `keep` in `pandas`.

Answer (score 36):

The `data.table` package also has `unique` and `duplicated` methods of it's own with some additional features.

Both the `unique.data.table` and the `duplicated.data.table` methods have an additional `by` argument which allows you to pass a `character` or `integer` vector of column names or their locations respectively

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 val = c(10,20,30,10,20,30))

unique(DT, by = "id")
#    id val
# 1:  1  10
# 2:  2  10

duplicated(DT, by = "id")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Another important feature of these methods is a huge performance gain for larger data sets

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1e8, 1e5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))
DT <- copy(DF)
setDT(DT)

microbenchmark(unique(DF), unique(DT))
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr       min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
# unique(DF) 44708.230 48981.8445 53062.536 51573.276 52844.591 107032.18   100   b
# unique(DT)   746.855   776.6145  2201.657   864.932   919.489  55986.88   100  a 


microbenchmark(duplicated(DF), duplicated(DT))
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval cld
# duplicated(DF) 43786.662 44418.8005 46684.0602 44925.0230 46802.398 109550.170   100   b
# duplicated(DT)   551.982   558.2215   851.0246   639.9795   663.658   5805.243   100  a
```

Answer (score 16):

the general answer can be
for example:

```
df <-  data.frame(rbind(c(2,9,6),c(4,6,7),c(4,6,7),c(4,6,7),c(2,9,6))))



new_df <- df[-which(duplicated(df)), ]
```

## output:

```
      X1 X2 X3
    1  2  9  6
    2  4  6  7
```

Comment: Be cautious when using `-which`, this will lead to error if there are no duplicates, use `df[!(duplicated(df)), ]` may be safer.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a very simple, fast `dplyr`/`tidy` solution:

**Remove rows that are entirely the same:**

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

**Remove rows that are the same only in certain columns:**

```
iris %>% 
  distinct(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a good approach and can remain in pipes. One note for the first option above, you don't need .keep_all = TRUE, as leaving distinct unqualified, it evaluates the entire data frame to my knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

With `sqldf`:

```
# Example by Mehdi Nellen
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

Solution:

```
 library(sqldf)
    sqldf('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM df')
```

Output:

```
  a b
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 B 4
4 B 1
5 C 2
```

Comment: This has the overhead of setting up an entire SQL database. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by setting up an entire SQL database? That is one of the main advantages: 'with sqldf the user is freed from having to do the following, all of which are automatically done: database setup, writing the create table statement which defines each table, importing and exporting to and from the database'. It is not  an optimal solution, but handy for those familiar with SQL.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove duplicate rows of a dataframe**

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mtcars

# Remove duplicate rows of the dataframe
distinct(mydata)
```

In this dataset, there is not a single duplicate row so it returned same number of rows as in mydata.

**Remove Duplicate Rows based on a one variable**

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mtcars

# Remove duplicate rows of the dataframe using carb variable
distinct(mydata,carb, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

The .keep_all function is used to retain all other variables in the output data frame.

**Remove Duplicate Rows based on multiple variables**

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mtcars

# Remove duplicate rows of the dataframe using cyl and vs variables
distinct(mydata, cyl,vs, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

The `.keep_all` function is used to retain all other variables in the output data frame.

*(from: http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/remove-duplicate-rows-r-using-dplyr-distinct-function/ )*

Answer (score 3):

Or you could nest the data in cols 4 and 5 into a single row with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% nest(V4:V5)

# A tibble: 1 × 4
#                      V1    V2    V3             data
#                  <fctr> <int> <int>           <list>
#1 platform_external_dbus   202    16 <tibble [5 × 2]>
```

The col 2 and 3 duplicates are now removed for statistical analysis, but you have kept the col 4 and 5 data in a tibble and can go back to the original data frame at any point with `unnest()`.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also be solved by selecting first row from each group where the group are the columns based on which we want to select unique values (in the example shared it is just 1st column).

Using base R :

```
subset(df, ave(V2, V1, FUN = seq_along) == 1)

#                      V1  V2 V3     V4 V5
#1 platform_external_dbus 202 16 google  1
```

In `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% slice(1L)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1L], by = V1]
```

If we need to find out unique rows based on multiple columns just add those column names in grouping part for each of the above answer.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = "platform_external_dbus", class = "factor"), 
V2 = c(202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L), V3 = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L), V4 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("google", 
"hughsie", "localhost", "space-ghost.verbum", "users.sourceforge"
), class = "factor"), V5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```