# Removing duplicate rows on the basis of specific columns

Tags: r

How can I remove the duplicate rows on the basis of specific columns while maintaining the dataset. I tried using these [links1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicate-rows-in-r), [link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/removing-duplicated-rows-from-r-data-frame)

What I want to do is I want to see the ambiguity on the basis of column 3 to 6. If their values are same then the processed dataset should remove the rows, as shown in the example:

I used this code but I gave me half result:

```
Data <- unique(Data[, 3:6])
```

Lets suppose my dataset is like this

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
 1  2  2  1  5  4  12 A  3  5  6  2  1
 1  2  2  1  5  4  12 A  2 35  36 22 21
 1  22 32 31 5 34  12 A  3  5  6  2  1
```

What I want in my output is:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
 1  2  2  1  5  4  12 A  3  5  6  2  1
 1  22 32 31 5 34  12 A  3  5  6  2  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is `unique` from `data.table`.  It has the `by` option.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), use `unique` and specify the columns within the `by`

```
 library(data.table)
 unique(setDT(df1), by= names(df1)[3:6])
 #   A  B  C  D E  F  G H I J K L M
 #1: 1  2  2  1 5  4 12 A 3 5 6 2 1
 #2: 1 22 32 31 5 34 12 A 3 5 6 2 1
```

`unique` returns a `data.table` with duplicated rows removed.

Comment: @ayush What is the other question

Comment: I have already have the dummy solution but it isn't accepting in my original dataset. I tried every possible permutation in my code but it won't work. Can I mail you the ques? or you can ping me over mail so that i can do that.

Comment: @ayush I am using sim to connect to the net.  Downloading big datasets is costly for me.  Can't you provide a dummy example that mimics your original dataset as a new post

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your data is stored as a dataframe, you could try:

```
Data <- Data[!duplicated(Data[,3:6]),]
#> Data
#  A  B  C  D E  F  G H I J K L M
#1 1  2  2  1 5  4 12 A 3 5 6 2 1
#3 1 22 32 31 5 34 12 A 3 5 6 2 1
```

The function `duplicated()` returns a logical vector containing in this case information for each row about whether the combination of the entries in column 3 to 6 reappears elsewhere in the dataset. The negation `!` of this logical vector is used to select the rows from your dataset, resulting in a dataset with unique combinations of the entries in column 3 to 6.

Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out a mistake in my previous post.