# Take first entry in repeated measures in R

Tags: r, unique

df:

```
ID     Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
A0001   358 11.25   37428   0
A0001   279 14.6875 38605   0
A0013   367 5.125   40152   1
A0014   337 16.3125 38624   0
A0020   367 8.875   37797   0
A0020   339 9.625   39324   0
```

want an output to keep only the first unique entry by ID, i.e.

```
ID     Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
A0001   358 11.25   37428   0
A0013   367 5.125   40152   1
A0014   337 16.3125 38624   0
A0020   367 8.875   37797   0
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicate-rows-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `duplicated` function returns `TRUE` for elements that have already appeared in a vector. Since you want the first occurrence of `ID`, just use

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
```

Comment: It worked great. thanks!