# How to integrate set of vector in multiple data.frame into one without duplication?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, merge

I have position index vector in data.frame objects, but in each data.frame object, the order of position index vector are very different. However, I want to integrate/ merge these data.frame object object in one common data.frame with very specific order and not allow to have duplication in it. Does anyone know any trick for doing this more easily? Can anyone propose possible approach how to accomplish this task?

## data

```
v1 <- data.frame(
  foo=c(1,2,3),
  bar=c(1,2,2),
  bleh=c(1,3,0))

v2 <-  data.frame(
  bar=c(1,2,3),
  foo=c(1,2,0),
  bleh=c(3,3,4))

v3 <-  data.frame(
  bleh=c(1,2,3,4),
  foo=c(1,1,2,0),
  bar=c(0,1,2,3))
```

## initial output after integrating them:

```
initial_output <- data.frame(
  foo=c(1,2,3,1,2,0,1,1,2,0),
  bar=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
  bleh=c(1,3,0,3,3,4,1,2,3,4)
)
```

## remove duplication

```
rmDuplicate_output <- data.frame(
  foo=c(1,2,3,1,0,1,1),
  bar=c(1,2,2,1,3,0,1),
  bleh=c(1,3,0,3,4,1,2)
)
```

## final desired output:

```
final_output <- data.frame(
  foo=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,0),
  bar=c(0,1,1,1,2,2,3),
  bleh=c(1,1,2,3,3,0,4)
)
```

How can I get my final desired output easily? Is there any efficient way for doing this sort of manipulation for data.frame object? Thanks

Comment: Also, `library(data.table) ; unique(rbindlist(mget(ls()), use.names = TRUE))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, remove the duplicates with `distinct` and `arrange` by 'bar'

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(v1, v2, v3) %>%
             distinct %>%
             arrange(bar)
#    foo bar bleh
#1   1   0    1
#2   1   1    1
#3   1   1    3
#4   1   1    2
#5   2   2    3
#6   3   2    0
#7   0   3    4
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use use `mget`/`ls` combo in order to get your data frames programmatically (without typing individual names) and then use `data.table`s `rbindlist` and `unique` functions/method for great efficiency gain (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicate-rows-in-r/36058634#36058634))

```
library(data.table)
unique(rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "v\\d+")), use.names = TRUE))
#    foo bar bleh
# 1:   1   1    1
# 2:   2   2    3
# 3:   3   2    0
# 4:   1   1    3
# 5:   0   3    4
# 6:   1   0    1
# 7:   1   1    2
```

As a side note, it usually better to keep multiple `data.frame`s in a single list so you could have better control over them

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
# combine dataframes
df = rbind(v1, v2, v3)

# remove duplicated
df = df[! duplicated(df),]

# sort by 'bar' column
df[order(df$bar),]
    foo bar bleh
7   1   0    1
1   1   1    1
4   1   1    3
8   1   1    2
2   2   2    3
3   3   2    0
6   0   3    4
```