# Eliminate duplicate dates in dataframe in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame as given below. How can I get a new data frame that eliminates duplication of dates: 6/15/2018 and 6/28/2018 and have a data frame with only  unique values

```
 Date        Hrs
6/14/2018   364.8
6/15/2018   372.6
6/15/2018   381.9
6/21/2018   383.3
6/22/2018   394.5
6/25/2018   411
6/28/2018   423.9
6/28/2018   424.9
```

Comment: How do you tell which of the two values for 6/15 you want to keep?

Comment: Which Hrs record you wanna remove where there's a duplicate? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) zoo** You can create a zoo series without duplicates by using `read.zoo` and specifying an `aggregate` function like this.  In the example we assumed you want the last of any duplicates but we can use `mean`, `median`, `function(x) head(x, 1)` or other functions for other aggregates.

```
library(zoo) 
z <- read.zoo(DF, format = "%m/%d/%Y", aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
```

Now `plot(z)`, `lattice::xyplot(z)` or `ggplot2::autoplot(z)` will plot it, `fortify.zoo(z)` will convert it to a data frame, etc.

**2) base** We can use `aggregate` in base like this:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
aggregate(Hrs ~ Date, DF2, function(x) tail(x, 1))
```

or we can use any of the aggregate functions mentioned in (1).

```
## Note

Lines <- " Date        Hrs
6/14/2018   364.8
6/15/2018   372.6
6/15/2018   381.9
6/21/2018   383.3
6/22/2018   394.5
6/25/2018   411
6/28/2018   423.9
6/28/2018   424.9"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: In the data frame the dates are in Y-m-d format and I get the following error
> z <- read.zoo(nonduplicate, format = "%Y/%m/%d", aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
Error in read.zoo(nonduplicate, format = "%Y/%m/%d", aggregate = function(x) tail(x,  : 
  index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

Comment: If you paste the code in the Note at the end into R and then paste the code in the answer then it works.   If I run this which creates DF3 with yyyy/mm/dd dates it also works.  `DF3 <- transform(DF, Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y/%m/%d")); z <- read.zoo(DF3, format = "%Y/%m/%d", aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))`  You will need to provide a reproducible example to say more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to keep the first row of two duplicates:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df[c('date')]),]

df

##     date   hrs
##6/14/2018 364.8
##6/15/2018 372.6
##6/21/2018 383.3
##6/22/2018 394.5
##6/25/2018 411.0
##6/28/2018 423.9
```

Comment: dear gos, can you help me if I want to keep the second row of two duplicates