# How do I group_by if the column that I want to summarize with has all the same values

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse

```
   x l
1  1 a
2  3 b
3  2 c
4  3 b
5  2 c
6  4 d
7  5 f
8  2 c
9  1 a
10 1 a
11 3 b
12 4 d
```

The above is the input.

The below is the output.

```
   x l
1  1 a
2  3 b
3  2 c
4  4 d
5  5 f
```

1. I know that column l will have the same value for each group_by(x).
2. l is a string

Comment: I think you can just pass the whole data frame to `unique`.

Comment: you can use `distinct` or use `group_by(x) %>% summarise_all(first)`

Comment: distinct or duplicated

Comment: Bunch of options: `unique(df)`, `distinct(df)`, `df %>% distinct(x, l)`. `df %>% group_by(x, l) %>% summarize()`, `df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(l = first(l))`... many more. There are small differences if other columns are involved, but any of these will work on the example you show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 0):

**# Creation of dataset**

```
x <- c(1,3,2,3,2,4,5,2,1,1,3,4)
l<- c("a","b","c","b","c","d","f","c","a","a","b","d")
df <- data.frame(x,l)
```

**# Simply call unique function on your dataframe**

```
dfu <- unique(df)
```