# deleting rows with same multiple value on one column

Tags: r, dplyr

i have 3 column and 2600 rows of accoustics dataset. the 3 column is "Ping_Number", "Latitude" and "longitude".

[image]

for each ping number, i would like to retrain the first row of ping number "1" (and so on) and delete the rest of ping number "1" and the result like this.

[image]

I have tried using `dplyr` library using `filter` command, but it not satisfy with my needs.

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look [Remove duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicated-rows).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `dplyr` for that, just do:

```r
df <- unique(df[,1:3])
```