# Merging two Dataframes row wise with Duplicates in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with duplicate rows. I want to merge with another dataframe such that each duplicate row is accounted for.

For Example,

```
df1:

   A    B    C
1  100  200  300
2  400  500  600
3  100  200  300

df2:

   A    B    C
1  100  200  300
2  600  700  800
```

After Merge: It should return

```
   A    B    C
1  100  200  300
```

But when I did:

```
merge(x=df1, y=df2)
```

I get

```
   A    B    C
1  100  200  300
2  100  200  300
```

Its returning two rows despite df2 having that row only once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicated-rows)

Comment: `unique(merge(df1, df2))`

Answer (score 1):

A contemporary tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  filter(duplicated(.)) %>%
  distinct(across(everything()))
  
#     A   B   C
# 1 100 200 300
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(100L, 400L, 100L), B = c(200L, 500L, 200L
), C = c(300L, 600L, 300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                 -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c(100L, 600L), B = c(200L, 700L), C = c(300L, 
                                                                  800L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is `match` after `paste`ing the columns together

```
 df1[match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1), nomatch = 0),]
    A   B   C
1 100 200 300
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(100L, 400L, 100L), B = c(200L, 500L, 200L
), C = c(300L, 600L, 300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c(100L, 600L), B = c(200L, 700L), C = c(300L, 
800L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think I would run into problem is there are two rows in df2 too. or If df1 has 3 duplicate rows, and df2 has 2 matching rows.

Comment: @MeghanathL try the updated solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can use `intersect` in `dplyr`

```
> intersect(df1,df2)
    A   B   C
1 100 200 300
```