# finding indices of duplicate rows - follow up

Tags: r

i am looking for a way for a way to find indices of duplicate rows.
after searching here i found this - [Find indices of duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows)

that looks good but i wanted to ask if there was a way to "clump" the indices of the repeated rows together. i tried asking this in a comment but the system won't let me.

the thing is- i have duplicate cells in my DF. i need to know the location of both rows where there was a duplicate for me to go through the original data and which one of them is wrong. 
a simple output of which indices are duplicate means i still have to find the "twin" by myself.
any ideas?

again, i apologize for asking a new question when this is clearly a follow up to an already asked question.

Comment: Sven's answer does not give you the desired results?

Comment: it's great for finding which cells are duplicates but i need to have them paired so i can look them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this, using the sample data from the related question:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,1,5,6,4,2,1))
x <- lapply(df$a, function(x) which(df$a == x))
names(x) <- df$a

> x
#$`1`
#[1]  1  5 10
#
#$`2`
#[1] 2 9
#
#$`3`
#[1] 3
#
#$`4`
#[1] 4 8
#
#$`1`
#[1]  1  5 10
#
#$`5`
#[1] 6
#
#$`6`
#[1] 7
#
#$`4`
#[1] 4 8
#
#$`2`
#[1] 2 9
#
#$`1`
#[1]  1  5 10
```

You could also do:

```
df$twin <- sapply(x, toString)
#   a     twin
#1  1 1, 5, 10
#2  2     2, 9
#3  3        3
#4  4     4, 8
#5  1 1, 5, 10
#6  5        6
#7  6        7
#8  4     4, 8
#9  2     2, 9
#10 1 1, 5, 10
```

Comment: thank you!
quick follow up- all the cells that have twins appear twice. 
is there a way around it? maybe with unique()?

Comment: You can try running `unique` on the resulting data. I can't currently test it, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a result that has all duplicated rows grouped together.

```
# example: want to group based on duplicates in df$a
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,1,5,6,4,2,1),b=1:10,c=21:30)
do.call(rbind,lapply(which(table(df$a)>1),function(x)df[df$a==x,]))
#      a  b  c
# 1.1  1  1 21
# 1.5  1  5 25
# 1.10 1 10 30
# 2.2  2  2 22
# 2.9  2  9 29
# 4.4  4  4 24
# 4.8  4  8 28
```

So in this example `df` has 3 rows with `df$a==1`, 2 rows with `df$a==2` and 2 rows with `df$a==4`. All other rows have unique values of `df$a`. This assembles a new data frame with only the duplicated rows, grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use to mark all the duplicates in an object:

```
allDup <- function (value) 
{
    duplicated(value) | duplicated(value, fromLast = TRUE)
}
```

It scans from the front and then the back to mark them all.