# Find duplicated elements with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried using the code presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts) to find ALL duplicated elements with `dplyr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
mutate(cyl.dup = cyl[duplicated(cyl) | duplicated(cyl, from.last = TRUE)])
```

How can I convert code presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts) to find ALL duplicated elements with `dplyr`? My code above just throws an error? Or even better, is there another function that will achieve this more succinctly than the convoluted `x[duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, from.last = TRUE)])` approach?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

I guess you could use `filter` for this purpose:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  filter(n()>1)
```

Small example (note that I added `summarize()` to prove that the resulting data set does not contain rows with duplicate 'carb'. I used 'carb' instead of 'cyl' because 'carb' has unique values whereas 'cyl' does not):

```
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarize(n=n())
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#
#  carb  n
#1    1  7
#2    2 10
#3    3  3
#4    4 10
#5    6  1
#6    8  1

mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% summarize(n=n())
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#  carb  n
#1    1  7
#2    2 10
#3    3  3
#4    4 10
```

Comment: I also mention the `add_count` function that adds the `n` column on which we can then filter: `mtcars %>% add_count(carb) %>% filter(n>1)` gives the same result with the additional `n` column.

Comment: Note that this results in a grouped dataframe; subsequent use of verbs like 'distinct' will have different results than they would on an ungrouped dataframe; to convert back to an ungrouped data containing only the duplicated records, use ungroup() (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html)

Comment: Newer versions of dplyr you can use only `filter` together with the `.by` argument without having to use `group_by`: `mtcars |> filter(n() > 1, .by = carb)`. This has the advantage of not having to do any `ungroup` after.

Answer (score 58):

Another solution is to use `janitor` [package](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor):

```
mtcars %>% get_dupes(wt)
```

Comment: Note that the result of this has all instances of duplicates in the data. For example, if you ran `get_dupes(data.frame(x=c(1,1,1)))` you would get the whole df back. `get_dupes` also adds a column of counts. See [here](http://sfirke.github.io/janitor/reference/get_dupes.html).

Answer (score 24):

The original post contains an error in using the solution from the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts). In the example given, when you use that solution inside mutate, it tries to subset the cyl vector which will not be of the same length as the mtcars dataframe.

Instead you can use the following example with filter returning all duplicated elements or mutate with ifelse to create a dummy variable which can be filtered upon later:

```
 library(dplyr)

 # Return all duplicated elements
 mtcars %>%
   filter(duplicated(cyl) | duplicated(cyl, fromLast = TRUE))
 # Or for making dummy variable of all duplicated
 mtcars %>%
   mutate(cyl.dup =ifelse(duplicated(cyl) | duplicated(cyl, fromLast = TRUE), 1,0))
```

Answer (score 23):

We can find duplicated elements with dplyr as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

# Only duplicated elements
mtcars %>%
  filter(duplicated(.[["carb"]])

# All duplicated elements
mtcars %>%
  filter(carb %in% unique(.[["carb"]][duplicated(.[["carb"]])]))
```

Comment: also the following syntax for multiple columns, `mtcars %>% filter(duplicated(.[c("carb", "cyl")])`

Answer (score 6):

```
# Adding a shortcut to the answer above
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
mtcars %>% count(carb)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>    carb     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1    1.     7
#> 2    2.    10
#> 3    3.     3
#> 4    4.    10
#> 5    6.     1
#> 6    8.     1
mtcars %>% count(carb) %>% filter(n > 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>    carb     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1    1.     7
#> 2    2.    10
#> 3    3.     3
#> 4    4.    10

# Showing an alternative that follows the apparent intention if the asker
duplicated_carb <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dup_carb = duplicated(carb)) %>% 
  filter(dup_carb)
duplicated_carb
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb dup_carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     TRUE
#> 2  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     TRUE
#> 3  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     TRUE
#> 4  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#> 5  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2     TRUE
#> 6  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2     TRUE
#> 7  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4     TRUE
#> 8  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4     TRUE
#> 9  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3     TRUE
#> 10 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3     TRUE
#> 11 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#> 12 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#> 13 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#> 14 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1     TRUE
#> 15 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2     TRUE
#> 16 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1     TRUE
#> 17 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1     TRUE
#> 18 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2     TRUE
#> 19 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2     TRUE
#> 20 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#> 21 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2     TRUE
#> 22 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1     TRUE
#> 23 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2     TRUE
#> 24 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2     TRUE
#> 25 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4     TRUE
#> 26 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2     TRUE
```

Comment: Re the "alternative", Marat's answer has 30 rows while yours has 26. I guess you can instead add one step to your original pipeline: `mtcars %>% count(carb) %>% filter(n > 1) %>% left_join(mtcars)` maybe with select(-n) first.

Answer (score 0):

Find duplicate value in data frame with column

```
df<-dataset[duplicated(dataset$columnname),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Boolean mask with duplicated():

```
iris %>% duplicated()
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE .... TRUE FALSE
[145] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And pass through square brackets indexing:

```
iris[iris %>% duplicated(),]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

Note: This approach is the closest thing to Pandas
that could be done with R and dplyr:

```
iris[iris %>% duplicated(), c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species")]
    Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
143          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution if you want to group duplicates using many columns

```
df%>%
  select(ID,COL1,COL2,all_of(vector_of_columns))%>%
  distinct%>%
  ungroup%>%rowwise%>%
  mutate(ID_GROUPS=paste0(ID,"_",cur_group_rows()))%>%
  ungroup%>%
  full_join(.,df,by=c("INFO_ID","COL1","COL2",vector_of_columns))->chk
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function `repeated` for it in package `xlr`.

See: https://rpubs.com/Eauleaf/xlr

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlr)

mtcars |> filter(repeated(cyl))
```