# Subset dataframe based on duplicate values in multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I subset the dataframe below to show only the rows were columns `AAA:CCC` all have the same value and retain the `IndID` field?

```
Dat <- data.frame(IndID = LETTERS[seq(1,10)],
                  AAA = c(1,5,3,2,3,1,5,4,6,2),
                  BBB = c(1,8,5,2,5,4,8,4,4,5),
                  CCC = c(1,5,3,2,3,5,5,4,6,5))

> Dat
   IndID AAA BBB CCC
1      A   1   1   1
2      B   5   8   5
3      C   3   5   3
4      D   2   2   2
5      E   3   5   3
6      F   1   4   5
7      G   5   8   5
8      H   4   4   4
9      I   6   4   6
10     J   2   5   5
```

I would like to return the following result.

```
Result <- data.frame(IndID = c("A", "D", "H"),
                  AAA = c(1,2,4),
                  BBB = c(1,2,4),
                  CCC = c(1,2,4))

> Result
  IndID AAA BBB CCC
1     A   1   1   1
2     D   2   2   2
3     H   4   4   4
```

I have found a number of related posts including [Find duplicated rows (based on 2 columns) in Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986657/find-duplicated-rows-based-on-2-columns-in-data-frame-in-r) and [Find duplicated elements with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244123/find-duplicated-elements-with-dplyr), among others, but have not been able to reproduce the desired result with three columns. For example, while close the code below shows all `distinct` rows, but with the undesired result of including rows were only two of the values are equal.

```
Dat %>% distinct(AAA, BBB, CCC)
```

I suspect the solution involves `filter` but an not sure how to obtain the desired result from the example [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244123/find-duplicated-elements-with-dplyr). A `dplyr` solution is preferred.

**Addition**
I also wonder if this could be applied to multiple factors. For example with the data below, which contains an `IndID` and three dates stored as factors, can a similar result be produced by either allowing factors or changing the factors to numeric values?

```
Dat <- structure(list(GenIndID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 5L), .Label = c("BHS_601", "BHS_603", "BHS_604", "BHS_605", 
"BHS_631", "BHS_635", "BHS_636", "BHS_637"), class = "factor"), 
    CptrDate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2016-02-01", 
    "2016-02-02", "2016-02-04", "2016-12-11"), class = "factor"), 
    DtLastAlive = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2016-02-04", 
    "2017-07-13", "2017-08-27"), class = "factor"), DtFnlFate = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2016-02-04", "2017-07-13", 
    "2017-08-27"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("GenIndID", 
"CptrDate", "DtLastAlive", "DtFnlFate"), row.names = c(82L, 83L, 
224L, 225L, 84L, 85L, 226L, 360L), class = "data.frame")


> Dat
    GenIndID   CptrDate DtLastAlive  DtFnlFate
82   BHS_601 2016-02-01  2017-07-13 2017-07-13
83   BHS_603 2016-02-02  2017-07-13 2017-07-13
224  BHS_635 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
225  BHS_636 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
84   BHS_604 2016-02-02  2017-07-13 2017-07-13
85   BHS_605 2016-02-02  2017-07-13 2017-07-13
226  BHS_637 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
360  BHS_631 2016-12-11  2017-08-27 2017-08-27
```

with the desired result being

```
> Dat[c(3, 4, 7),]
    GenIndID   CptrDate DtLastAlive  DtFnlFate
224  BHS_635 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
225  BHS_636 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
226  BHS_637 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
```

Comment: `Dat[apply(Dat[-1], 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1),]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another solution with `apply` and `all`:

```
Dat[apply(Dat[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x==x[1])),]
```

or with `filter_at` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Dat %>% 
  filter_at(vars(AAA:CCC), all_vars(. == .data$AAA))
```

**Result:**

```
  IndID AAA BBB CCC
1     A   1   1   1
4     D   2   2   2
8     H   4   4   4
```

**Edit:**

In response to OP's additional example, the `apply` example would work regardless of variable type. So the following would work for the new example:

```
Dat[apply(Dat[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x==x[1])),]
```

**Result:**

```
    GenIndID   CptrDate DtLastAlive  DtFnlFate
224  BHS_635 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
225  BHS_636 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
226  BHS_637 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
```

For `filter_at`, however, if the columns to compare are `factor`'s, one would need to first convert to `character`:

```
Dat %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-1), all_vars(as.character(.) == .data$CptrDate))
```

Notice that you only need to convert `.` to character, but not `.data$CptrDate` because factors can be compered with characters, but *not* with another factor with different levels.

An alternative would be:

```
Dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-1), as.character) %>%
  filter_at(vars(-1), all_vars(. == .data$CptrDate))
```

**Result:**

```
  GenIndID   CptrDate DtLastAlive  DtFnlFate
1  BHS_635 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
2  BHS_636 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
3  BHS_637 2016-02-04  2016-02-04 2016-02-04
```

Comment: is `filter_at` a new addition to `dplyr`?

Comment: @B.Davis I think it's been a while since release. What version of `dplyr` do you have? Check `sessionInfo()`

Comment: yea. I had 0.5.0 but just reinstalled and now have `filter_at`

Comment: @B.Davis Great. There is also `filter_all`, `summarize_at`, `summarize_all` etc. So for example if you don't have the `IndID` column, I would use `filter_all`

Comment: This works for my numeric data! perfect! I am also wondering if it can be applied to factors and have added an addition above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @B.Davis For `apply`, no need to convert. For `filter_at`, you will need to first convert to character. See my edits.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a subset of 3 columns you can use the DF[,] operator.

```
# DF[where rows have a value, select columns]
# [where rows where AAA==BBB==CCC, select all columns with ""]
temp <- Dat[Dat$AAA == Dat$BBB & Dat$BBB == Dat$CCC,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `range()` and `diff()`.

```
Dat[apply(Dat[ ,-1], 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))==0, ] 
#   IndID AAA BBB CCC
# 1     A   1   1   1
# 4     D   2   2   2
# 8     H   4   4   4
```

`range()` gives you the minimum and the maximum of a vector. `diff()` gives you the difference between values in a vector. If the difference between `min-value` and `max-value` is zero, you know all values are equal. If we apply this row-wise using `apply`, we get a `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector that we can use to index `Dat`.

---

Small examples to illustrate the logic:

```
test <- c(1, 5, 3)
minmax <- range(test)    # gives c(1,5)
diff(minmax)             # gives 4
diff(range(c(1, 1, 1)))  # gives 0
```

If we check for every row, whether or not `diff(range(your_row))` equals zero, we can use the output of that to index `Dat`, like we did above.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a vectorized solution:

```
Dat[do.call(function(...) pmax(...) - pmin(...), Dat[, -1]) == 0,]
#  IndID AAA BBB CCC
#1     A   1   1   1
#4     D   2   2   2
#8     H   4   4   4
```