# Remove duplicates in one column based on another column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, duplicates

I'm looking for a nicer way to do this in R. I do have one possibility but it seems like there should be a smart/more readable way.

I want to delete duplicates in one/more column only if a condition is met in another column (or columns).

In my simplified example I want to delete duplicates in column `X` only if column `Y` is `NA`, but keep `NA`'s in Y without a duplicated X.

```
testDF<- data.frame(X= c(1:4,4:8,8:12), Y = 1:14)
testDF$Y[c(4,6,10)]<- NA
```

My current solution is:

```
testDF[!(testDF$X %in% testDF$X[which(duplicated(testDF$X))] & is.na(testDF$Y)),]
```

or

```
library(dplyr)

testDF %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!(testDF$X%in% testDF$X[which(duplicated(testDF$X))] & is.na(testDF$Y)))
```

which both appear messy and confusing, and in a real application where I am going to be looking at more than two columns could get unworkable.

I was hoping for something more along the lines of:

```
 testDF %>% dplyr::filter(!(duplicated(X) & is.na(Y)))
```

but it `duplicated()` only identifies the second instance of a duplication so if `Y`'s `NA` is in line with the first of the duplicated X values then it will not be filtered out.

Preferably looking for a base or tidyverse solution as none of the rest of the script is using data.table

Comment: You current dplyr solution can be simplified to: `testDF %>% dplyr::filter(!(X %in% X[duplicated(X)] & is.na(Y)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just apply `duplicated` from both directions:

```
testDF %>%
  filter(!is.na(Y) | (!duplicated(X) & !duplicated(X, fromLast = TRUE) ))
```

(highly influenced by this: [Find duplicated elements with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244123/find-duplicated-elements-with-dplyr) - I'll let others decide if this is close enough to be a duplicate)

To make your code even more readable, you can even put this in a function (perhaps with a better function name than mine):

```
all_duplicates <- function(x) {
  duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
}
testDF %>%
  filter(!is.na(Y) | !all_duplicates(X) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a solutions using `duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)` shortly after asking the question but thought I'd leave it up to see what other approaches might be possible. This is very simply though and with it in its own function would make applying across other columns and criteria easy and readable

Answer (score 2):

We can arrange the columns, group by `X`, and then `slice` the first row. By doing this, we can get the non-NA row in `Y` if that row exists.

```
library(dplyr)

testDF %>%
  arrange(X, Y) %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#        X     Y
#    <int> <int>
#  1     1     1
#  2     2     2
#  3     3     3
#  4     4     5
#  5     5    NA
#  6     6     7
#  7     7     8
#  8     8     9
#  9     9    11
# 10    10    12
# 11    11    13
# 12    12    14
```

Comment: I really like this solution for this exact example, but I think that to apply to more columns when the my criteria may not be excluding `NA`s it might be more difficult to implement. +1 because for simple versions it will work well

Comment: Hmm, just realised that if I have multiple non-na duplicates this won't work though which would need to be included

Comment: @www, I am looking for the same solution and wonder if you've found a solid answer to this question where I have multiple rows with `NAs` or/and  `empty cells`?

Comment: @Alex You can post a new question with reproducible examples if your question is different from this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar idea like what @www suggested, arrange X and Y first, and then `filter` instead of `slice`.

The first filtering condition would be `row_number()==1` , as if `row_number == 1` it means X is distinct.
The second filtering condition would be `!is.na(Y)` , which would only keep any X whose Y is not NA.

```
testDF %>% arrange(X,Y) %>%  
      group_by(X) %>% filter(row_number()==1 | !is.na(Y)) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer but may get confusing if I wanted to apply to more columns with individual conditions

Comment: @Sarah, I am looking for the same solution and wonder if you've found a solid answer to your question in case you have multiple rows with `NAs` or `empty cells`?

Comment: @Mihai Chelaru, can you please advise, I just commented on your answer when there are multiple rows with `NAs` or `empty cells`?

Comment: @Alex I am the last editor of this answer, not the original author. DDZR is the author, so perhaps they can provide an update, but please be patient as their profile says they have not been online since May 23rd. I don't currently program in R so I'm afraid I can't be of any use here.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, thanks for the update anyway. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Alex I honestly cannot remember why I even asked this question, let alone what I ended up doing about it, sorry I can't be more helpful