# Find All Unique rows based on single column and exclude all duplicate rows

Tags: r

I have two requirements

1. find all duplicate values in single column
2. find all unique rows [opposite to first question] This should not include even single pair from duplicated rows

I'm Learning since last 2 weeks. Watching YouTube videos, Referring Stackoverflow and other websites, so not much. Please do refer if any material or courses.

so answer to my first question i found here 
([Find duplicated elements with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244123/find-duplicated-elements-with-dplyr))

```
# All duplicated elements
mtcars %>%
  filter(carb %in% unique(.[["carb"]][duplicated(.[["carb"]])]))
```

So i want opposite of this

Thanks

P.S. I have non technical background. I went through couple of questions and answers here, so i might have found the answer or needed some of tweaks and i totally ignored that

Comment: Do you need `mtcars %>%
+  filter(!(carb %in% unique(.[["carb"]][duplicated(.[["carb"]])])))`

Comment: This is quite unclear. For one thing, "find all duplicate values in single column and return the all rows [2 or more]" isn't a grammatical sentence. For another thing, you haven't provided any idea about what your data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably realised, `unique` and `duplicated` don’t quite what you need, because they essentially cause the retention of all distinct values, and just collapse “multiple copies” of such values.

For your first question, you can `group_by` the column that you’re interested in, and then retain just those groups (via `filter`) which have more than one row:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(mpg) %>%
    filter(length(mpg) > 1) %>%
    ungroup()
```

This example selects all rows for which the `mpg` value is duplicated. This works because, when applied to groups, dplyr operations such as `filter` work on each group individually. This means that `length(mpg)` in the above code will return the length of the `mpg` column vector of each group, separately.

To invert the logic, it’s enough to invert the filtering condition:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(mpg) %>%
    filter(length(mpg) == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Yes, Perfect. both of your answers works for me. Thank you.