# tidyverse filter behaviour I dont expect (%in% doesnt work with pull() )

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

When I try to filter a dataframe using the `%in%` operator using a `pull()` subfilter, It does not work.
However, When I store the `pull()` subquery in a variable, and then use the `%in%` operator on the variable, It does work.

I use as an example the well known mtcars dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- tibble(mtcars)
```

Say I want all the observations who share cyl+am+vs
The following code does not work:

```
mydf |> filter(mpg %in% 
mydf |> filter(duplicated(paste0(cyl,am,vs))) |> pull(mpg)
)
```

Error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `pull(...)`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

However, the same structure, using a variable work:

```
mpg_as_var <- mydf |> filter(duplicated(paste0(cyl,am,vs))) |> pull(mpg)
mydf |> filter(mpg %in% mpg_as_var)
```

I don't want to just take the duplicates, but also the first duplicated observations. otherwise it would've been a simple `filter(duplicated()) query`

Got any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? when you say *share cyl+am+vs* do you mean `cyl == am == vs`??

Comment: Your requested query sounds like it will also output rows which share ‘mpg’ with a row with duplicated values. That doesn’t arise in this particular dataset but could with others.

Comment: You have an order of operations problem. The `%in%` and `|>` have the same operator precedence (per the `?Syntax` help page) so they are evaluated left to right. But you seem to want to have the `|>` happen "first". Use parenthesis to control the order of operations. If you look at the output of `quote(mydf |> filter(mpg %in% mydf |> filter(duplicated(paste0(cyl,am,vs))) |> pull(mpg)))` you can see how it's interpreted by the parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244123/find-duplicated-elements-with-dplyr  Offers other approaches which will address the edge case I described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parenthesis around the vector you create, e.g.

```
      mydf |> filter(mpg %in% 
                       (mydf |> filter(duplicated(paste0(cyl,am,vs))) |> pull(mpg))
      )

# A tibble: 28 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 6  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
```

Comment: lol. what a simple solution. thanks. kinda shame i didnt think to do it myself. good ol' `c()`. I cant vote it up but it is a great solution. Obviously the program didn't understand i intended to evaluate the pull first. makes a lot of sense