# get connected components using igraph in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, connected-components

I would like to find all the connected components of a graph where the components have more than one element.

using the `clusters` gives the membership to different clusters and using `cliques` does not give connected components.

This is a follow up from

[multiple intersection of lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406560/multiple-intersection-of-lists-in-r/30406975?noredirect=1#30406975)

My main goal was to find all the groups of lists which have elements in common with each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need  `clusters`?

Comment: @user20650 yes. clusters with more than one element. sorry I meant clusters instead of connectedComp. Edited the question

Comment: The `?clusters` function returns cluster membership and size - should be easy enough to subset it to only include clusters with more than one node

Comment: @user20650 Is there any efficient way to do this instead of manually going through the results of `clusters`?

Comment: There is probably a function to extract this... but you can just use the results from `clusters`. One way: `cl <- clusters(g); lapply(seq_along(cl$csize)[cl$csize > 1], function(x) V(g)$name[cl$membership %in% x])`

Comment: @user20650 I guess you do not need the `$name` and why not you post the answer? Also we need to convert `vertex` type to numeric

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the results from `components` to subset your nodes according to the component size.

```
library(igraph)

# example graph
set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 1/20)
V(g)$name <- letters[1:20]
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
# get components
cl <- components(g)
cl
# $membership
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  4  5  5  6  7  8  9 10  3  5 11  5  3 12  5
# 
# $csize
# [1] 1 1 3 2 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 
# $no
# [1] 12


# loop through to extract common vertices
lapply(seq_along(cl$csize)[cl$csize > 1], function(x) 
                                         V(g)$name[cl$membership %in% x])
# [[1]]
# [1] "c" "n" "r"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "d" "f"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "e" "g" "h" "o" "q" "t"
```

Comment: Just for fun, here's another approach once you have the clusters: `grps <- with(cl, duplicated(membership)|duplicated(membership, fromLast=TRUE))` followed by `unname(split(V(g)$name[grps], cl$membership[grps]))`