# How to identify subnetworks in adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, subgraph

I have a network graph "G" based on the following edges:

```
library(igraph)

edges <- data.frame( 
  from=c(1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6),
  to=  c(2,3,5,6,7,6,7,7))

G <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges,  directed=F)
```

This example clearly contains 2 subnetworks, the first with nodes 1,2,3 and the second one with nodes 4,5,6,7. I would like to:

1. Identify to which subnetwork node "i" belongs to.
2. The number of nodes in each subnetwork.

Thus, in this example, the function will ideally create an object with as many rows as number of nodes in G, and two columns: the first contains a vector that indicatse the ID of the subnetwork and the second with the size (gsize) of the subnetwork. .

```
 result <- data.frame( 
  ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  gsize=c(3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4))

G <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges,  directed=F)
```

I am new using `igraph` so maybe there is a function to do this.

Comment: `components(G)` ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407769/get-connected-components-using-igraph-in-r/30407992#30407992

Comment: These are called *connected components* (not subnetworks). That is the keyword you need.

Comment: Thanks ! Components function was exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

If it's just disconnected components you are interested in:

```html
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

edges <- data.frame( 
  from=c(1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6),
  to=  c(2,3,5,6,7,6,7,7))

G <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d=edges,  directed=F) 


# create requested dataframe

df <- data.frame(node_ID = as.vector(V(G)), 
                 community = as.vector(components(G)$membership))

required_df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::inner_join(df %>% 
                      dplyr::group_by(community) %>% 
                      dplyr::count(name = "community_size")
                    )
```

If it is more complex clusters you are interested in:

```html
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

edges <- data.frame( 
  from=c(1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6),
  to=  c(2,3,5,6,7,6,7,7))

G <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d=edges,  directed=F) 

# find subnetworks using louvain algorithm and adding to community in graph

louvain_partition <- igraph::cluster_louvain(G)

G$community <- louvain_partition$membership

# create requested dataframe

df <- data.frame(node_ID = as.vector(V(G)), community = G$community)

required_df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::inner_join(df %>% 
                      dplyr::group_by(community) %>% 
                      dplyr::count(name = "community_size")
  )
```

Comment: re you edit: you can grab all the info from components without using joins: `with(components(G), data.frame(node = names(membership), component = membership, size=csize[membership]))`

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith ! The components function was what I was searching for.