# Remove all rows based on multiple columns

Tags: r

Following basic example:

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c","a","b")
v2 <- c(1,2,3,1,1)
v3 <- rnorm(5,5) 

dat <- data.frame(cbind(v1,v2,v3))
```

I want to remove all rows with same value in v1 and v2.

To remove duplicated rows I can use

```
dat[!duplicated(dat[,c("v1","v2")]),]

   v1 v2 v3
1  a  1 6.48929449801677
2  b  2 4.89050807004701
3  c  3 5.57089903349316
5  b  1 4.08152834124853
```

But I want to remove the first row also.

Does anyone have a simple solution? Maybe some option in duplicated which I was not able to identify.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `duplicated` with `fromLast=TRUE` option to search for duplicates in the reverse direction and then use `|` to get all the duplicates.  Negating the logical index gets only the index for unique rows which we subset later.

```
dat[!(duplicated(dat[,c("v1","v2")])|
     duplicated(dat[,c("v1", "v2")], fromLast=TRUE)),]
```