# how to select rows that have same absolute value of a number

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

```
    transaction  | sum
    -------------|--------
 1 | refill      | 1450
 2 | write-off   | -1450
 3 | refill      | 3500
```

I want to choose only those values that have same absolute value of a number. There are rows 1 and 2. How can I do it in R?

Comment: can you please dput your data?

Comment: What happens if there is a third row with `1450` or `-1450` ?

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that there is a user id too, so it should be selected within transactions of same user id

Comment: nurma please make sure to have a reproducible example and to add the DESIRED RESULT to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method, using Andre's dataset:

```
df1<-data.frame(index=1:6,sum=c(1,2,3,-1,3,4))
df1[duplicated(abs(df1$sum)) | duplicated(abs(df1$sum), fromLast = T),]
```

This is based on scanning for duplicates in forward order, then in reverse order, and then `OR`ing the result to match all duplicated cases. As described here: [Find indices of duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1<-
data.frame(index=1:6,sum=c(1,2,3,-1,3,4))

#  index sum
#1     1   1
#2     2   2
#3     3   3
#4     4  -1
#5     5   3
#6     6   4

keep <- abs(df1$sum) %in% abs(df1$sum[duplicated(abs(df1$sum))])

df1[keep,]

#  index sum
#1     1   1
#3     3   3
#4     4  -1
#5     5   3
```