# Create a new column based on a condition from the previous n rows in R

Tags: r

I received data in a csv. from a report pulled from Salesforce. Each row represents a transaction and the person that worked on the transaction. There are multiple cases where more than 1 person worked on the same transaction so in those cases there are duplicate rows that show the date, time stamp, location, office, etc. **except** for the person's name.

I want each row to represent one transaction and in the case where multiple people worked on the same transaction, a new column would be created to capture the other person's name.

This is what the data looks like:

```
Trans_ID | Name
================
1        | Dom Toretto
2        | Brian Oconnor
3        | Letty Garcia
3        | Mia Toretto
4        | Brian Oconnor
4        | Dom Toretto
4        | Letty Garcia
4        | Jesse
```

This is what I want:

```
Trans_ID | Name          | Name2        | Name3        | Name4
===============================================================
1        | Dom Toretto   | Letty Garcia |              |
2        | Brian Oconnor |              |              |
3        | Letty Garcia  | Mia Toretto  |              |
4        | Brian Oconnor | Dom Toretto  | Letty Garcia | Jesse
```

I want to do this in R, but if it is easier in SQL or Excel, that would work too.

Thank you!

**EDIT**
So I tried using case when and lag  in r to do this but now I have a new problem of deleting the rows that are no longer necessary. This may also be the wrong approach. Any ideas?

```
df<- data.frame(trans_id = c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4), 
Name = c("Dom Toretto","Brian Oconnor","Letty Garcia","Mia Toretto","Brian Oconnor","Dom Toretto","Letty Garcia","Jesse"))


df %>%
  mutate(
  Name2 =  case_when(
      trans_id == lag(trans_id) ~ lag(Name)
),
  Name3 = case_when(
  trans_id == lag(trans_id, 2) ~ lag(Name, 2)
),
  Name4 = case_when(
  trans_id == lag(trans_id, 3) ~ lag(Name, 3)
))
```

Comment: Please specify one language? It's currently too broad? **I received data in a csv. from a report pulled from Salesforce** What have you tried since then?

Comment: see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495471/5874001) on how to get the duplicate indexes and filter out the rows of the duplications afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work with `nest` and `map` functions, df:

```
df <- tibble(Trans_ID = c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4), 
             Name = c("Dom Toretto", "Brian Oconnor", "Letty Garcia", 
                      "Mia Toretto", "Brian Oconnor", "Dom Toretto", 
                      "Letty Garcia", "Jesse"))
```

Then nest on Trans ID and map over each dataframe:

```
 df %>% 
  nest(-Trans_ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(data, ~ mutate(.x, 
                              col_name = str_c("Name", row_number())) %>% 
                 spread("col_name", "Name"))
  ) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Returns:

```
  Trans_ID Name1         Name2       Name3        Name4
     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>        <chr>
1        1 Dom Toretto   NA          NA           NA   
2        2 Brian Oconnor NA          NA           NA   
3        3 Letty Garcia  Mia Toretto NA           NA   
4        4 Brian Oconnor Dom Toretto Letty Garcia Jesse
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have a situation here where each row has a different number of entries. That tells me that most likely you don't want to store this data in a dataframe or matrix-like object. Those objects are primarily for square data, which yours is not. I don't know your use case, but I would probably store this data in a list of character vectors. You can get this using `split()`

```
output <- split(df$Name,df$Trans_ID)
```

If you have reason to store this in a square data object with missing values, there are lots of ways to convert the above. For example, using data table.

```
library(data.table)
squareoutput <- rbindlist(lapply(output,function(x)data.table(x)),fill=TRUE)
```