# R calling non-unique values duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I have the following csv file as dataframe called `key`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy7bxlh2oyvh141/key.csv?dl=0

When I run:

```
dup <- key[which(duplicated(key$Genotype)), ]
```

I get a dataframe with 100 rows, most of actually appear unique:

```
> head(dup)
       Pot  Genotype
193 142698 PI-177384
194 142700 PI-178900
195 142702 PI-179275
196 142704 PI-179276
197 142706 PI-179277
198 142712 PI-179690
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: `duplicated` only returns TRUE the second time a value appears. For example `duplicated(c(1,2,2))` returns FALSE, FALSE, TRUE. The first 2 hasn't been seen before but the second is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least very related): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a df of duplicated rows, you'll have to alter the code to include a `!`

This should work:

```
dup <- key[which(!duplicated(key$Genotype)), ]
```

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to click the green checkmark to accept the answer if it solved your question.