# How to check if I have repeated elements in a matrix (checking rows and columns) in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
M = matrix(data = 1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
print (M)

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    1    4    8
## [3,]    3    6    9
```

I wanna check that elements in row [1,] are equal to elements at row[2,]. Or which elements at row[1,] are equal to elements at column[,3], for example.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Exactly what kinds of duplicates are you looking for? Something like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495345/find-indices-of-duplicated-rows

Comment: I put an image, I need to check the interactions beetween indexes left and indexes from right side.

Comment: Please don't use images when sharing data. We can't copy/paste into R for testing. We also don't need your entire data, just a small, reproducible example that makes it clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: # Create matrix do store indexes
# Search for the sequences
# Search in left sequences
# Search in right sequences
# mark repeated sequences with idx index
# Now we will search for all righ sequences
# Search for all right sequences
# give an index to the sequence we are looking for
# mark repeated sequences with idx index
# Put back the column representing the interaction
#also check for repeated sequences in the original file

Comment: I wanna check for repeated sequences in the file. So, which command I will use?

Comment: I would avoid reassigning the result back to your same variable name. General approach would be to make a copy of the matrix (can be by reference) shifted forward by one and down by one, and then compare `matrixorig == matrixshift` (w/o the `not`, etc) this will give you columns of true/false values and you can look for any `True` entries all the way down a column.

Comment: As mentioned, if you post a little 4x4 example it will make it easier for us to give a concrete solution.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. Sorry for my incomprehension, I'm begginer here.